# What is common practice for hosting a server that is not user-facing and just for API use?

Tags: ssl, architecture, dns, server, web-hosting

I have a server on DigitalOcean that I use to host my professional website. I have an additional server I just use to store data and make API calls to, but it just has the IP address, not a domain name.

Is this... normal? I want to have the transport to and from the server over SSL, so I should get a domain name for it, right?

Should I just be doing this on the same server I host my website? Separating the concerns seemed wise there.

Answer (score 0):

Separation is a good idea, yes. I'd recommend naming the API server api.whatever-your-domain-is.com, and buying an SSL certificate for that hostname.